# Reminder of promised resource

Tags: formality, politeness

Someone promised me a resource and I haven't received it yet. I am tired of waiting so I would like to remind this person that he/she promised me something and ask about the situation.

My question is how can I ask about it in a polite kind of way? Can I ask:

> What is the situation on this resource?

Comment: This seems to be more a question of manners than of English, and it may be closed accordingly. A perfectly polite query would be something along the lines of *Can you provide me with an update regarding the status of [insert resource name]?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take this as a word choice question: *are the words you chose consistent with your intent to ask politely?* **Yes**. There is nothing impolite about the words you chose, even interpreted very broadly. For example, the question does not blame the person or express impatience.